# ReferenceError on lazy

Tags: javascript, scroll, lazy-loading, addeventlistener

I'm trying to add [this simple image lazyload](https://codepen.io/FilipVitas/pen/pQBYQd) in my wordpress site because looks better and smaller than other js scripts but Im getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined` at `window.addEventListener('scroll', _.throttle(lazyLoad, 16));`

The full js code:

```
let lazyImages = [...document.querySelectorAll('.lazy')];
let inAdvance = 300;

function lazyLoad() {
  lazyImages.forEach(image => {
    if (image.offsetTop < window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset + inAdvance) {
      image.src = image.dataset.src;
      image.onload = () => image.classList.add('loaded');
    }
  });

  // if all loaded removeEventListener
}

lazyLoad();

window.addEventListener('scroll', _.throttle(lazyLoad, 16));
window.addEventListener('resize', _.throttle(lazyLoad, 16));
```